# is keras LSTM supposed to work without an input_shape parameter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am using an LSTM for fake news detection and added an embedding layer to my model.

It is working fine without adding any input_shape in the LSTM function, but I thought the `input_shape` parameter was mandatory. Could someone help me with why there is no error even without defining `input_shape`? Is it because the embedding layer implicitly defines the `input_shape`?

Following is the code:

```
model=Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(total_words, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(LSTM(64,))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01,decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data,train['label'], epochs=30, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to provide an `input_length` to the `Embedding` layer. Furthermore, if you use a `sequential` model, you do not need to provide an input layer. Avoiding an input layer essentially means that your models weights are only created when you pass real data, as you did in `model.fit(*)`. If you wanted to see the weights of your model before providing real data, you would have to define an input layer before your `Embedding` layer like this:

```
embedding_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,))
```

And yes, as you mentioned, your model infers the `input_shape` implicitly when you provide the real data. Your `LSTM` layer does not need an `input_shape` as it is also derived based on the output of your `Embedding` layer. If the `LSTM` layer were the first layer of your model, it would be best to specify an `input_shape` for clarity. For example:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape=(10, 5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

where 10 represents the number of time steps and 5 the number of features. In your example, your input to the `LSTM` layer has the `shape(max_length, embedding_dim)`. Also here, if you do not specify the `input_shape`, your model will infer the shape based on your input data.
For more information check out the Keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential).

Comment: I'm a little confused here
First you mentioned that if an input layer is avoided then the weights are created only when you pass real data.
You said the model infers the input_shape implicitly when the real data is provided but you also said if the LSTM layer were the first layer in my model then I need to specify input_shape. Can you please clarify this..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, updated my answer.

Comment: It's clear now!